# u-sql UDF debug in Local

Tags: debugging, u-sql

I want to debug UDF code in local mode that is I am executing the u-sql script on local and not on azure portal.
Please let me know how to debug the UDF in local mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please start here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-data-lake-tools-local-run.

Thank you,
Guy